# Error en respuesta Api restfull y Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, restful

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy aprendiendo Laravel + Vuejs y a crear un SPA (Single Page Application) el detalle es que mi restfull api responde con un mensaje en caso de que la consulta genere error, Ejemplo, mi controlador APIController de inicio de sesion se encarga de validar las credenciales por medio de JWT, esta asi:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $token = null;

        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($input)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Invalid Email or Password',
            ], 401);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'accessToken' => $token,
        ]);
    }
```

Funciona perfecto, recibe el error:

```
success: false
message: "Invalid Email or Password"
```

pero como muestro el "message" directamente en la notificacion?

El componente encargado del login esta configurado asi:

```
loginJWT({ commit }, payload) {

      return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        jwt.login(payload.userDetails.email, payload.userDetails.password)
          .then(response => {

            // If there's user data in response
            if(response.data) {
              // Navigate User to homepage
              router.push(router.currentRoute.query.to || '/')

              // Set accessToken
              localStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.data.accessToken)

              // Update user details
              commit('UPDATE_USER_INFO', response.data.userData, {root: true})

              // Set bearer token in axios
              commit("SET_BEARER", response.data.accessToken)

              resolve(response)
            }else {
                reject("message", response.data.message)
            }

          })
          .catch(error => { reject(error) })
      })
    },
```

si reviso la consola todo va perfecto, muestra el error json pero no lo toma, es decir solo se queda cargando, alguien me podria explicar como tomar los valores del json y mostrarlos?

Answer (score 0):

Si respondes sin json, recibiras un objeto y puedes tratarlo como tu codigo js, de esta forma

```
return [
    'success' => true,
    'accessToken' => $token,
];
```

O bien, parsea el json recibido

```
.then(resp => {
    let response = JSON.parse(resp)
    // If there's user data in response
    if(response.data) {
    }
 ...//Resto del codigo
```